# What are the differences between gel and foam gear?

Tags: equipment, sparring, protective-equipment

What is the advantage and drawback of gear with gel inside? Is it better than foam gear or is it commercial? Specifically is gel good for gloves, shin guards, body armor, or headgear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use gel handwraps for boxing, and have used gel gloves. My experience with foam is that it compresses and shifts over time in your gloves, whereas gel gloves seem to do this less, and last a bit longer as a result.

This is entirely anecdotal, based on my personal experience.

Comment: I believe that foams (to a certain degree) rely upon the air trapped in the foam structure and this dissapates over time, whereas gels are just a dense viscous liquid.

Answer (score 1):

Gels are supposed to dissipate the impact better than foams, which in theory should result in better protection.